# Storing decryptable passwords without requiring the private key every request

Tags: php, laravel, encryption

I've search around for a while and I can't seem to find a solution.

I'm looking to allow users to enter in a PIN (the users private key) to access all of their stored passwords in a Laravel 5.3 app.

Right now without storing the private key, the user will need to enter in their PIN for every password they want to see. I was wondering if there was a way to temporarily store the private key securely *somehow* for the duration of the session after they've entered their PIN, so I can allow the users to browse and view their passwords after entering their PIN once, rather than on a *per password* basis.

Google Password Manager does this and I'm just curious how they manage to do this without requiring me to enter in my Gmail password for every password I want to view.

Does anyone have any insight on this subject? Thanks!

Comment: At the most, I would probably hash the pin with a salt and use that as a kind of private key to decrypt the passwords. But that's my limited understanding of how to do this or how I might attempt to do this.

Comment: @jardis That's fine and dandy, but how would I go about not requiring the PIN on every request? Would I store it somewhere? And if so, where?

Comment: I suppose you could use it as a sort of session, and verify the content on each request to make sure someone's not forging it. If it's a hash then you don't have to worry about it being decrypted on the client end; just that the hashed value is sent by a verified source (ie. signed by your own server in some way).

Comment: I'm curious why a session wouldn't suffice for this

Comment: just thoughts about what I would do. The issue is that you have to store the pin, probably, encrypted somewhere. Where ever you store it. It must have a limited lifetime. 10 - 15 minutes for example. Also, This only allows viewing of the actual passwords. If the user want to change it they have to re-enter the pin again. That should be reasonably secure. The attackers only have a small  time window to get access to the pin. I would be tempted to store the encrypted pin in a separate datastore. Not in the session or the main database. I am a little paranoid though ;-/

Comment: just curious - what method did you finally decide to use - if any?

Comment: Hey @RyanVincent, I haven't come to one yet really, but I like your idea. So essentially, I'll have users create a PIN during setup and I'll one way hash it using `bcrypt()`, then, I'll have a temporary unique / randomly generated "access code" that's stored in the users session that's generated from their origin PIN (when they've entered their PIN correctly), which would allow them to view passwords for the duration of the session? Then I can use a middleware to validate every request for the users access code?